# If 4 specific checkboxes are selected, then unselect them and select only the "all items" one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

Now I have this form

```
<ul>
<li>
    <label>
        <input name="INTERESTS" type="checkbox" value="a" id="all"><span>All items</span>
    </label>  
</li>
<li>
    <label>
        <input name="INTERESTS" type="checkbox" value="b" id="1"> <span>Item 1</span>
    </label>
</li>
<li>
    <label>
        <input name="INTERESTS" type="checkbox" value="c" id="2"> <span>Item 2</span>
    </label>
</li>
<li>
    <label>
        <input name="INTERESTS" type="checkbox" value="d" id="3"> <span>Item 3</span>
    </label>
</li>
<li>
    <label>
        <input name="INTERESTS" type="checkbox" value="e" id="4"> <span>Item 4</span>
    </label>
</li>  
</ul>
```

And this javascript

```
var $others = $('input[name="INTERESTS"]').not('#all')
$('#all').change(function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        $others.prop('checked', false)
    }
});
$others.change(function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        $('#all').prop('checked', false)
    }
})
```

[Test it at jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g3aqx31c/9/)

If the "all items" checkbox is selected then the others are unselected. It works great, but now I need that if all items are selected (Item 1 to Item 4), then unselect them and select only the "all items" checkbox. Any thoughts on this?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this?

```
var $others = $('input[name="INTERESTS"]').not('#all')
$('#all').change(function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        $others.prop('checked', false)
    }
});
$others.change(function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        $('#all').prop('checked', false)

        if( $('input[name="INTERESTS"]:checked').not('#all').length == $others.length){ // if checked inputs count equals to the input count
          $('input[name="INTERESTS"]').not('#all').prop('checked', false); // uncheck except "all" input
            $('#all').prop('checked', true) // check "all items"
        }
    }
})
```

[fiddle result](https://jsfiddle.net/g3aqx31c/17/)

Hope helps,

Answer (score 0):

```
var check_box_1 = document.getElementById("1");
var check_box_2 = document.getElementById("2");
var check_box_3 = document.getElementById("3");
var check_box_4 = document.getElementById("4");
var check_box_all = document.getElementById("all");

function MyFunction(){
    if(check_box_1.checked && check_box_2.checked && check_box_3.checked && check_box_4.checked)
    {
       check_box_all.checked = true;

       check_box_1.checked = false;
       check_box_2.checked = false;
       check_box_3.checked = false;
       check_box_4.checked = false;
     }
}
```

Then, add

```
onclick = "MyFunction()"
```

to your 1, 2, 3, 4, checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

Change the other checkbox click event to this.

```
$others.change(function () {
        $('#all').prop('checked', $('input[name="INTERESTS"]:checked').not('#all').length == $others.length)
    });
```